# Calculate FF interaction energy of small molecular dimers

Tags: density-functional-theory, gromacs, forcefields, turbomole, amber

I have a set of molecular dimers (~25 atoms) for which DFT-D3 interaction energies are calculated by Psi4 and Turbomole program. Now I want to compare these values against Force-Field methods like UFF/Amber/OPLS. I have known that in Gromacs or Amber suite of programs can do that but for these small systems, I think those will be overkill.
Any suggestion of programs which can calculate single point energies of the small dimers?

Comment: What do you mean by overkill? [Lammps](https://www.lammps.org/) might have this capability. See their [documentation](https://docs.lammps.org/Howto_bioFF.html) for details. Maybe their [user forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/lammps/mailman/lammps-users/) might have some insight.

Comment: I tried to use gromacs, and had to go through a lot of process. Those are relevant for the large simulation but my concern is just few atoms in vaccum. This is why I said overkill.  Okay, let's see lammps.

Comment: They all do the same thing, none will be less overkill, some may just assign automatic parameters, rather than getting your input, but, this should not make you feel better... on the contrary, you should lose sleep if you only have to push a couple buttons.

Comment: The ultimate simplicity would be to just write your own FF code. It would be short for dimers. No need for ewald or anything. Just sum the lennard-jones and simple coulomb interactions. The longest part of the program would be reading in atom type lennard-jones parameters and charges and storing them in some kind of structure for recall later.

Comment: Most MD codes also have the ability to perform a geometry optimization. I would suggest using that so that you can be sure the structure has the appropriate minimum with each force field. Otherwise you have to hack the MD code to only run for one step which I always find concerning because it's hard to know if it will move the geometry before printing the energies. Also, make sure you don't use periodic boundary conditions, otherwise the MD package will probably use them automatically and give incorrect results.

Comment: You should note though that UFF, OPLS, and similar MM force fields are designed for condensed phase simulations meant to reproduce experimental results. So, you will probably get terrible answers compared to ab initio, and even if you sometimes get good results in the gas phase with these force fields, it is for the wrong reason.

Comment: @jheindel The problem is, I don't want to optimize, just single point energies. The structures are already optimized at mp2 in gas phase. So the problem is very simple. Just need to calculate the energy at respective FF models.

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay Right. You probably still want the single point energies at the minimum of the corresponding force field, even if you also want them at the MP2 geometries. The optimization will give you both at once because the first energy in the optimization routine is the single point energy at the MP2 geometry.

Comment: @jheindel It may not be the case every time. You said earlier that FF are parameterized for condensed phases, and MP2 optimized are in vaccum, secondly, I am not very sure about that, but many FF do not account for explicit dispersion while MP2 does a lot. This might change the geometry. 
Even though, I can take the risk. I am looking at LAMMPS code. If you have some small tutorial for this purpose, please share.

Comment: OpenMM should be able to do this pretty easily, if the FF you want is in a format that can be converted by https://github.com/openmm/openmmforcefields, and if you have a way to get the topology information (atom types) into OpenMM. Update the Q with an example configuration/topology information and I can see if I can the details to work. However, I second @jheindel's point that this isn't expected to be a good comparison. (This kind of single-point comparison is exactly what is done to test the conversion in that GH repository.)

Comment: @dwhswenson, thanks. I will do that and let you know very soon.

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay Any update?

Comment: @NikeDattani Not yet, having some issue with the server.....

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay How about now?

Comment: I'm closing the question for now, but its mainly for bookkeeping purposes. Whenever you get a chance to update the question, let me know and I'll reopen it.